# Hibernate OneToMany collection is loaded even if lazy

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have an entity `User`, with a property `wishes` that should be lazy loaded as stated in the FetchType attribute of the @OneToMany annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@DynamicUpdate
public class User extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name = "user_email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Wish> wishes = new HashSet<>();

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof User)) return false;

        final User user = (User) other;

        if (!user.getEmail().equals(getEmail())) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = getEmail().hashCode();
        result = 29 * result;
        return result;
    }
```

The entity `Wish` follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wish",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "product_id"}))
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Immutable
public class Wish extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof User)) return false;

        final Wish wish = (Wish) other;

        if (!wish.getId().equals(getId())) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = getId().hashCode();
        result = 29 * result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the following code in a service class:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User getUserWithRolesOnly(String username) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findOneWithRoles(username);
        ....
        // HERE, user.wishes is loaded up even if it is LAZY
        ...
        return user;
    }
```

Repository code:

```
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.roles " +
        "WHERE u.email = ?1")
    Optional<User> findOneWithRoles(String email);
```

The user object is loaded along with the wishes. How come? I would expect it not to be loaded if not requested (since it's LAZY fetched).

Why is `wishes` loaded instead?

I see it being loaded also by debugging the hibernate code. Logs:

```
2021-10-02 12:08:38.501 TRACE 20808 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [com.test.impl.User.wishes#3]
```

Comment: What do you do with `optionalUser` after retrieving it?

Comment: @JoãoDias return to the client, but I put a breaking point right after optionalUser and I already saw the data being loaded up in the logs. I know that even if lazy, if you demand it with get (or is demanded i.e. during serialization), it load those data. But I am not doing it actually. Still hibernate loads it. Weird

Comment: When you put a breakpoint and navigates through the object it is exactly the same as demanding it with a get. "I already saw the data being loaded up in the logs" --> which logs are you talking about? Hibernate logs or your own logs?

Answer (score 0):

The collection is loaded because some code, probably Jackson during serialization, is accessing the data through e.g. reflection. Try adding `@JsonIgnore` to your `wishes` association to observe that Jackson is the problem here.

To solve this properly, you need DTOs that prevent access to information that you don't want to expose and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getEmail();
    Set<RoleDto> getRoles();

    @EntityView(Role.class)
    interface RoleDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!